# DelimitMate plugin for vim not working

Tags: vimrc, delimiter-matching, plugin-pathogen, plugin-delimitmate

I am new to vim, so I installed the plugin DelimitMate to my vim. But it is not working in my vim -version  7.4.1689.My plugin manager in pathogen.I searched on everywhere to solve this problem but nothing worked. I used the following commands in vim to install it:

```
$ cd ~/.vim 
$ git submodule add git://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate.git bundle/delmitmate 
$ git submodule init && git submodule update
```

Not only this, the help commands are not working either: `:h delimitmate` and `:help DelimitMate` like commands are not working

Also my other plugins are working well in my vim , so thats not the fault of with my vim. So please anybody can tell me what wrong am I doing.

Also in my .vimrc file `filetype plugin indent on` has been added . 
So please somebody help me sort out this problem.

Comment: Maybe you should raise an issue on the github repo of this project instead.